# Vuex: working with complex objects and state-changing functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Suppose I'm using an external API which works with `Machine` objects. You can create a `Machine` with `createMachine`, which will give you a complex object with several nested properties, and a set of functions to alter state on that object.  The API provides for example: `loadMemory`, `sleep`, `connectDevice`. (Imagine anything similar, this is just an example).

I want to mantain a global Vuex `Machine` object, so I've an action to dispatch that initial creation and store the returned object just like:

```
actions: {
createChannel({ commit, state }, params) {
      m.createMachine(params).then(
        function (newMachine) {
          commit('setMachine', newMachine);
        }
      ).catch(err => { console.error("Error"); } )
    }
}
```

The mutation is pretty straightforward in this case:

```
  setMachine(state, machine) {
      state.machine = machine;
    }
```

Now that API set for the "Machine" objects, as we know has a bunch of state-modifying calls -we don't know what specific fields they change-.
As they modify state, and I want to use them to affect the global `Machine` object in the Vuex store,  **I would like to wrap them in actions**.

An action could call

`this.state.machine.loadMemory(mem.addr)`

But if this call itself modified the `machine` object, how do I commit the new state? Should I clone the old object, apply the state-changing method and replace the object ?

I know cloning is not an easy task.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-mount your complex object. According to the example, the mutation could be:

```
loadMemory(state, newAddr) {
  const { machine } = state;

  state.machine = {
    ...machine, // set all machine's properties
    addr: newAddr,
  };
}
```

It works in any level of nested objects you want. Another example:

```
loadMemory(state, newValue) {
  const { machine } = state;
  const { machineObjProp } = machine; 

  state.machine = {
    ...machine, // set all machine's properties
    machineObjProp: {
       ...machineObjProp, // set all machineObjProp's properties
       value: newValue,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is using lodash [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep), it will copy app properties and methods of object

```
import _ from lodash

this.state.machine.loadMemory(mem.addr)
const copyMachine = _.cloneDeep(this.state.machine)
this.$store.commit('setMachine', copyMachine)
```